# How to stop flickering in sidescroller that uses tiles?

Tags: java, swing

So I am trying to stop my program from flickering but from other peoples problems I can't find a solution that applies to my code. It just flickers and I've seen a suggestion from another persons post to change to paintComponent but I don't see how it works when compared to paint. Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks.

```
package runalreadypls;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class GameGen extends JFrame implements KeyListener{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7177541209377865450L;
    Random rand = new Random();//Random generator for map
    double move = 0;//Moves graphics generation 
    int timed = 750;//Moving delay
    int speed = 2;//Moves Faster
    int [][] world=new int[10][100];//Map generation
    int WIDTH = 720;//Width of frame/window
    int HEIGHT = 480;//Height of frame/window
    String exitMSG;//Exit message
    String user;//username
    int charX = 0;//Starting coordinates for character
    int charY= 4;
    BufferedImage img1;//Graphics generation
    static double score = 0;//Score of player
    GameGen(){//Start game
        super("Runner");//Set frame specifications
        this.setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setFocusable(true);
        this.setVisible(true);
        //Adds spacebar listener
        addKeyListener(this); 
        //Starts world generation
        worldGen();
        //Paints world
        repaint();

        //Swing Timer for moving of character and background
        Timer timer = new Timer(timed ,null);
        timer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //Increasing speed

                if (speed < 400){
                    speed = speed + 5;
                }
                timer.setDelay(timed - speed);
                //Increasing score
                score = score + 3;
                //Moving character
                charX= charX + 1;
                //Checks if game is over
                if(gameOverCollision()){
                    timer.stop();//Ends "delayed loop" 
                }
                //Gravity
                //If charY is not below the screen to prevent array out of bounds
                if (charY < 9){
                    if (world[charY+1][charX] == 0){//Moves character down/Gravity
                        charY = charY+1;
                        deleter();//Deletes character previous coords
                        mover();//Moves character coords on array
                    }
                }
                deleter();//Deletes character previous coords
                mover();//Moves character coords on array
            }
        });

        timer.start();//Starts "delayed loop" / swing timer 
    }
    public void deleter(){//Deletes character previous coords so there is only one character on the screen
        for(int x = 0;x <9;x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++){
                if (world[x][y] == 2){
                    world[x][y] = 0;    
                } 

            }
        }

    }

    public void mover(){//Moves character on the array
        world[charY][charX] = 2;
        repaint();
    }

    /*
     * 
     * 0 = Background
     * 1 = Surface
     * 2 = Player
     * 3 = Below Surface
     * 
     * */

    public void worldGen(){
        int xAt = 5;
        world[4][0] = 2;//Character placement
        world[5][0] = 1;//First tile placement
        for (int x = 1; x < 100; x++){  //Starting place
            int X =3;
            X = rand.nextInt(X)+1;//Random Number Generator 
            if (xAt <= 6 && xAt>=3){//If where the ground is at is between 7 and 2 (exclusive)then it will generate normally 
                if (X == 1){
                    xAt =xAt+ 1;
                    world[xAt][x] = 1;
                }else if (X == 3){  
                    xAt =xAt - 1;
                    world[xAt][x] = 1;
                }else if (X==2){
                    world[xAt][x]=1;
                }
                /*
                 * If where the ground is at is too low between 7 and 9 (which is the bottom 3 tiles)
                 * then it will generate with more chances of going up instead of staying the same
                 * 
                */
            }else if(xAt >6 && xAt <9){
                if (X==1 || X==3){
                    xAt =xAt- 1;
                    world[xAt][x] = 1;
                }else if (X==2){
                    world[xAt][x]=1;
                }
                /*
                 * If where the ground is at is too low between 1 and 4((exclusive) which is the top 3 tiles) 
                 * then it will generate with more chances of going down instead of staying the same
                 * 
                */
            }else if(xAt >1 && xAt <3){
                if (X==1 || X==3){
                    xAt =xAt+ 1;
                    world[xAt][x] = 1;
                }else if (X==2){
                    world[xAt][x] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        //Generates ground below the surface
        for(int x = 0;x <9;x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++){
                if (world[x][y] == 1){
                    world[x+1][y] = 3;
                } 
                if (world[x][y] == 3){
                    world[x+1][y] = 3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 100)); 
        g.drawString(Integer.toString((int) score), 220, 100);
        //Checks through 2d array to generate images
            for(int x = 0;x <9;x++){
                for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++){
                    if(world[x][y] == 0){
                        try {//If background then accesses background image
                            img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/runalreadypls/Background.png"));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } else if(world[x][y] == 1){
                        try {//If surface then accesses surface image
                            img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/runalreadypls/Ground.png"));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }else if (world[x][y] == 2){ 
                        try {//If surface then accesses character image
                            img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/runalreadypls/Character2.png"));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }else if (world[x][y] == 3){
                        try {//If below surface then accesses below surface image
                            img1 = ImageIO.read(new File("src/runalreadypls/Foreground.png"));
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    g.drawImage(img1,(int) (45*(y-move)),60*x,null);//Draws images in procedural order
                }
            }
            move = move + .65;//Moves screen

    }
    /*
     * 
     * WALL collision
     * If player misses jump
     * Game is over
     * 
     * 
     * */
    public boolean gameOverCollision(){
        //Checks if the player has missed a tile or if they have finished the map
        if(world[charY][charX] == 1||charX == 99){
            /*
             * 
             * Adds current players score to the high score file
             * 
             * */
            try {
                fileAppend();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*
             * 
             * Sorts high scores in order of greatest to least 
             * 
             * */
            try {
                fileSort();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //Deletes window
            dispose();
            //Exit Msg
            exitMSG = "Thank you for playing " +Game.name() +" your score is: " + score;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exitMSG, "Thank you for Playing!", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            //Recreates main menu
            new Game();
            //Reseting Score and speed
            score = 0;
            speed = 2;

            return true;
            //Checks if player has finished the map
        }else{
            return false;
        }       
    }
    public void fileSort()throws IOException,FileNotFoundException{
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();//Array list to store integers
        File file = new File("highscores.txt");//File 
        BufferedReader br = null;//br
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));//br
        String text = null;//text
        while ((text = br.readLine()) != null) {//Putting integer into list
            list.add((int) Double.parseDouble(text));//Converting line text to int and putting into list
        }
        if (br != null) {//closing
            br.close();
        }
        Collections.sort(list);//sort list
        Collections.reverse(list);//reverse list for descending order
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("highscores.txt");//Write to file
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        for(Integer lists: list) {
          bw.write(lists);//WRiting to file
          bw.newLine();//New line
        }
        bw.close();//Closing
        fw.close();
    }
    public void fileAppend()throws IOException{
        //Declaring writers
        FileWriter fw = null; 
        BufferedWriter bw = null; 
        PrintWriter pw = null; 
        fw = new FileWriter("highscores.txt", true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw); pw = new PrintWriter(bw); 
        pw.println(score); //Adding to file
        //Closing
        pw.close(); 
        bw.close(); 
        fw.close(); 
    }
    /*
     * 
     * Listens to spacebar input to move character up a tile
     * 
     * */
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if(charY<9 && charY >0){
            if (e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
                if(world[charY][charX+1] == 1){
                    charY-=1;//Moving character Y coords up a tile
                    deleter();//Deletes character previous coords
                    mover();//Changing player's tile in array
                }
                if(world[charY][charX+1] != 1){ 
                    score = score -3; //Substracts score if player jumps early  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   
    }
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: First and foremost -- study prior similar questions, and you'll see one big and common problem is that you're drawing directly within the JFrame's paint method and thus don't use double-buffering. As the many answers will tell you: draw within the paintComponent of a JPanel as this will grant double buffering by default. As always, search before asking, as a search on Swing animation flickering will surely have already told you this.

Comment: For example, check [this Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+animation+flickering). The first few hits tell exactly what I've told you above.

Comment: Other suggestions: draw background images to a BufferedImage, and then draw the image within the same paintComponent method.

Comment: And also, ***NEVER*** have code like this within a painting method: `ImageIO.read(new File("src/runalreadypls/Background.png"));`. You're reading in a file within the most time critical piece of code of your program, a file that you could (and should) easily read once and save as a variable.

Comment: Ok thank you and sorry for the trouble I will definitely keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar suggestions to the many similar questions:

- Draw within the `protected void paintComponent` method of a JPanel, not within a JFrame's paint method. This will give you double buffering by default.
- Never read in a file or resource within a painting method. This method's speed is the most important factor in the perceived responsiveness of your program and you should do nothing to slow it down. It should be for painting and painting only.
- Instead, read the image into a variable *once*, and then draw the image from the variable within `paintComponent`.
- Paint background images to a BufferedImage and then draw that within the paintComponent method.

Comment: Thank you very much!! it no longer flickers

Answer (score -1):

**Double Buffer Drawing**

in the run() method, you should have something like this --

```
while(running) {
  gameUpdate();
  gameRender();
  repaint();      // Note: I would not use this either, you should also
                  // have thead.sleep() call to stop event coalescence: when 
                  // JVM is overloaded by repaint() request, JVM may combine 
                  // request, causing rendering request to be skipped and
                  // animation to "jump."
}
```

Well, inorder to reduce flikering -- "jump" -- you should apply a **double buffering** thechnique. One way to do this to have the gameRender() draw into its own Graphics object, which would represent an image the same size of the screen.

My Example:

```
// Global variables for off-screen rendering
private Graphics dbg;
private Image dbImage = null;

private void gameRender() {
/* Draw the current frame to an image buffer*/
    if(dbImage == null) { // create the buffer
        dbImage = createImage(PWIDTH, PHEIGHT);
    if(dbImage == null ) {
        System.out.println("dbImage is null");
        return;
    }
    else
        dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    }
    //clear the background
    dbg.setColor(Color.white);
    dbg.fillRect(0, 0, PWIDTH,  PHEIGHT);

    // Draws game elements
    // ...
    if(gameOver)
        gameOverMessage(dbg);

} // end gameRender()
```

dbImage is placed on screen by the paintComponent() as a result of the repaint() request in the run() loop -- while(running)...gameUpdate(), Render(), repaint()..
Here is the call that would place dbImage on screen. This call is made after rendering steps have been completed (the above code):

```
public void paintComponent(Graphic g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (dbImage != null)
    g.drawImage(dbImage, 0,0,null);
}
```

If extensive drawing is done directly to the screen, the process may take long enough to become noticiable by the user. the call to drawImage() in paintComponent() is fast enough that the change from one frame to the next is preceived as instantaneous.

**paintComponent should be kept simple**

Futhermore, I would also convert to **active rendering**, since the call to repaint() is only a request, its hard to know when repaint() has completed... which means the sleep time in the animation thread (while(running)...ect) is basically a guess.. When I say sleep time, I mean this:

```
running = true;
while (running) {
    gameUpdate(); // Game state is updated
    gameRender(); // Render to a buffer
    paintScreen(); // Note: Change from repaint() to paintScreen(),
                   // will explain later.                                      
try {
  Thread.sleep(20); // sleep a bit.. 20 ms to be exact.
} catch(InterruptedException ex){}
} // end of run()
```

There should be a specified sleeping time for for 3 main reasons: 1. it stops the animation thread, which frees up the CPU for other task, like garbage collection by the JVM. 2. the sleep call gives the preceeding request to repaint() time to be proccessed. 3. sleep reduces the chances of event coalescence because it give the JVM time to complete tasks instead of combining task causing "jumping" affect in the animation.

However, using the repaint() request, as stated before the sleep time is little more than a guess; if the specified time is too long, then the animation speed is impaired for no reason. if the dely is too short, then the repaint requests may be queued by the JVM and skipped if the load is too lard, causing "flickering"

Active rendering puts the task of active rendering the buffer into your hands, allowing the render time to be accurately measured.

like so,

```
running = true;
while (running) {
    gameUpdate(); // Game state is updated
    gameRender(); // Render to a buffer
    paintScreen(); // Note: Change from repaint() to paintScreen(),
                   // will explain later.                                      
try {
  Thread.sleep(20); // sleep a bit.. 20 ms to be exact.
} catch(InterruptedException ex){}
System.exit(0);

 /**
 * Actively render the buffer image to screen
 */
private void paintScreen() {
    Graphics g;
    try {
        g = this.getGraphics(); // get the panel's graphic context
        if ((g != null) && (dbImage != null))
            g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); // sync the display on some
                                            //  systems
        g.dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Graphics context error: " + e); 
    } // end catch
} // end paintScreen()
} // end of run()
```

I would like to explain more, but the rest I leave to you to explore, it is a world of fun.. Forgive any puncuation and spelling -- I am in a rush.. Goodluck

respectfully,
@author James Stowell - !di0m -

**Full implementation w/ concerns of seperating updates from rendering mentioned in the comments section below:**

Since I prefer writing 3D games, I will use the J3DTimer, you may employ other high resolution timers, the JMF timer is an option...

The run() method without possible pauses:

```
    private static final int MAX_FRAME_SKIPS = 5;
    // number of frames that can be skipped in any one animation loop
    // i.e the game state is updated but not rendered 
    private static final int NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD = 16;
    // number of frames with a delay of 0 ms before the animation 
    // thread yields to other running threads.

    @Override 
    public void run() {
    /* Repeatedly update, render, sleep so loop takes close
     * to period nsecs. Sleep inaccuracies are handled.
     * The timing calculation use the Java 3D timer.
     * 
     * Overrruns in update/renders will cause extra updates
     * to be carried out so UPS ~== requested FPS 
     */

    long beforeTime, afterTime, timeDiff, sleepTime;
    long overSleepTime = 0L; // Number zero of type long (0L)
    int noDelays = 0;
    long excess = 0L;

    beforeTime = J3DTimer.getValue();

    running = true;
    while (running) {
        gameUpdate(); // Game state is updated
        gameRender(); // Render to a buffer
        paintScreen(); // Draw buffer to screen

        afterTime = J3DTimer.getValue();
        timeDiff = afterTime - beforeTime;
        sleepTime = (period - timeDiff) - overSleepTime; // Time left in this
                                                         // loop

        if (sleepTime > 0) { // Some time left in this cycle
        try {
            Thread.sleep(sleepTime/1000000L); // nano -> ms
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            overSleepTime =
                    (J3DTimer.getValue()-afterTime) - sleepTime;
        }
            else { // sleepTime <= 0; frame took longer than the period
                excess -= sleepTime; // store excess time value
                overSleepTime = 0L;

                if (++noDelays >= NO_DELAYS_PER_YIELD) {
                    Thread.yield(); // Give another thread a chance to run
                    noDelays = 0; // New thread, no delays.
            } // end inner if
        } // end outer if
        beforeTime = J3DTimer.getValue();

        /* If frame animation is taking too long, update the game state
         * without rendering it, to get the updates/sec bearer to required
         * FPS
         * */
        int skips = 0;
        while((excess > period) &&(skips < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS)) {
            excess -= period;
            gameUpdate(); // Update state, but don't render
            skips++;
        }
    } // end while

    System.exit(0); // So enclosing JApplet/JFrame exits
} // end of run()

/**
 * Actively render the buffer image to screen
 */
private void paintScreen() {
    Graphics g;
    try {
        g = this.getGraphics(); // get the panel's graphic context
        if ((g != null) && (dbImage != null))
            g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync(); // sync the display on some
                                            // systems
        g.dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Graphics context error: " + e); 
    } // end catch
} // end paintScreen()
```

Comment: Swing is double buffered by default - Using `getGraphics` could causing flickering as it's operating outside the normal paint cycle of Swing, which would erase what ever's been painted to the component previously, it can also return `null`. If you want to use/promote active painting, then you should use a `BufferStrategy` which does both of things you're trying to do, but does it in such away as to resolve the issues you're creating

Comment: You double buffering approach is also dangerous, as `paintComponent` could try and paint the image before your "main loop" has finished updating it, which could cause dirty paints, instead, you should have a "active" and "update" buffer, the "active" buffer is what gets painted to the screen, the "update" buffer is what is currently been updated, you'd then switch between these two - to ensure only what you want displayed on the screen is painted

Comment: ^^ that is why you would use a timer for the Thread.sleep()... As I stated, "There should be a specified sleeping time." Using a timer allows us to calculate the before and after time difference which would be used to calculate the sleep time -- sleepTime = (period - timeDiff) - overSleepTIme; -- being that period would be a global variable for iteration time e.g desired FPS is 100, 1000/100 = 10ms, period would = 10 and overSleepTime = 0L, then you would implement the rest of the code into the animation loop, I left this out of my answer because the question asked was about his paintComponent

Comment: But, you don't control WHEN Swing does it's painting - it can paint at any time for any reason, might do it while you're waiting, might do it while you're updating the buffer - This is why, if you want that level of control, you should use a `BufferStrategy` which is designed to provide an actual active painting, multiple buffered solution, rather than some pseudo attempt

Comment: With respect, you origin premise is flawed - Swing is double buffered to start with AND if you want to implement a active painting system, you should use a `BufferStrategy`

Comment: What I just said was that I left the integration of a timer for them to figure out -- since this was not the question. The integration of the timer would stop the painting of the image before the "main loop" has finished updating.... Im adding to my answer to enlighten people who may need to know this. Respectfully, Thank you for your input.

Comment: I updated my answer.. Understand that this is a possible way for any game, even more so, any 3D game without pausing to be implemented WITH the best possible outcome for speed & rendering of animation for a game using this implementation. I dont believe I desive -1 on my answer.

Comment: Swing is double buffered, so you don't need to implement your own; if you did, your implementation is flawed, as I stated; `getGraphics` is not recommended and should be avoid; If you want control over the paint process, use a `BufferStrategy` - it's what's its designed for; Assuming that your "main loop" is it's own thread, this doesn't stop Swing from painting over everything you've done either while you're updating the UI or in the "sleep" phase of the loop, which could trigger ore flickering

Comment: Hi sorry to intrude on your heated discussion but in what scenario would a Bufferstrategy be used?

Comment: In the book, _Killer Game Programming in Java_, by Andrew Davison, he states the following: " A core technology for a good game is its animation algorithm,"(pg.13). Furthermore he states, that the sleep () call on the thread is necessary for the three reasons, which I stated originally (pg.18). There must be an accurate time for sleeping; if the amount of sleep time given is too small, frames will be queued in the JVM, if too long they will be skipped (pg18).

Comment: Repaint () request are done by the JVM & cannot be measured easily (21). No sleep time is satisfactory since the time taken to update and render a frame vary depending on the activity taking place in the game so, it must be calculated every time (pg.22). Repaint should be removed, as is the overriding of    paintComponent()(pg.22);
Its functionality has been incorporated into paintScreen ().

Comment: “The frame’s graphic context may be changed by the JVM when the canvas is resizing or when it comes to the front window after being behind others the context may disappear if the application or applet exits while the thread is running after being behind other. For these reasons the graphic’s contents must be freshly obtained each time it is needed (by calling getGraphics())”(page 22.).

Comment: The gameRender () draws to its own Graphics object (dbg) which represent the same size of the screen (dbgImage) while printScreen(). The author writes, “ This technique is known as double buffering, since the rendering are not applied directly to the screen” (pg.19). Continuing, “The principle advantage of double buffering is to reduce on-screen flicker”(pg.19)

Comment: An animation’s loop execution speed is unconstrained because it matters what operating system. “Slow machine may loop 20 times per second; and a fast machine may loop 80 times, making the game 4x faster or unplayable,” writes Davidson (pg.22). Furthermore, if the desired FPS is 100 then 1000/100 == 10 ms, if update/render steps take 6ms , then sleep() should be called for 4 ms. Of course this is different on each platform, so must be calculated at run time.

Comment: which I did with the J3DTimer. In order to have created a good game that is reliable and has fast game play across all the various operating systems that will run it, these specifications should be met.

Comment: I believe I am correct, my syntax & answers meet all those specifications. you should remove your -1. Thank you.